# How to create a drop down list in odoo12 and fill in it by values from 1 to 5 for example

Tags: widget, odoo, selection

i have to create a drop down list (using widget selection) and fill in it by numbers from 1 to 3 for example. below the code who i writed but the drop down list is empty.
 Any help please

Comment: Please share the code you wrote?

Comment: Client.xml:<field name="cin_number" widget="selection"/>                                                                  client.py:                                                    class ResPartnerForm(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    cin_number = fields.Selection([('one', '1'), ('two', '2'), ('three', '3')], string=" selection field")                                                                                                               The problem is that my Drop down list is empty

Comment: Please check the field in models from front view. See if the field type is selection? Please try with different dropdown values and check if it is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a selection field or many2one field. I will explain both cases.

Selection field

```
one_selection = fields.Selection([('one','1'),('two','2'),('three','3')],string="Selection Field)

xml: <field name="one_selection"/>
```

Many2one field

```
one_id = fields.Many2one('new.model',string="Many2one field)

xml: <field name="one_id" widget="selection"/>
```

Please be informed that in selection field the option will come automatically. But in many2one field we have to create the option for that we have to create a new model as below:

```
class NewModel(models.Model)
_name="new.model"
```

provide the fields. and create a menu for the new model, where you can create the options that will come in the many2one list

I think you need only a selection field.

Comment: I tried this but my drop down list stay empty:                                                                                        
                                                                                                                               
 class ResPartnerForm(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    Note= fields.Selection([('one', '1'), ('two', '2'), ('three', '3')], string="selection field")

Comment: in my client.xml:                                                                                                                      <field name="Note"  widget="selection"/>

Comment: Don't add widget for a selectional field in xml.

Comment: when i remove the widget it becomes a simple text box

Comment: I think note is already text field in res_partner model. So please add new custom field.